# Can you use a manifest file to tell a VB6 app .EXE to access certain versions of OCXs?

Tags: dll, regfreecom

I have a VB6 app `.EXE` which uses Microsoft-created `OCXs` such as `RICHTX32.OCX` and `MSACAL70.OCX`.  I experience problems with both these `OCXs`.  Essentially this is a DLL-Hell problem.

If I use a `.manifest` file for the `.EXE`, can I instruct the .EXE to access specific copies of these `OCXs` in the application directory, thereby avoiding any issues regarding registration of these `OCXs`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put them into App.Path because you risk their being self-registered by the VB6 runtime on use, thus contributing further to DLL Hell.

A subfolder would be preferable because it won't be found by the DLL Search.  An appropriate application manifest for your program could redirect access to this subfolder, and the necessary isolation info can go into the application manifest saving you the effort of creating assembly manifests for your dependencies.